# Is it possible to attach file while filling in Adobe Forms pdf?

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I know that forms in .pdf made by Adobe Acrobat can act like questionnaire or application blank for filling input fileds and saving results, but is it possible in a way to add more interactiviry to them 
- add file upload or attachment to resulting document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *kind of* possible.

You'll need to add Javascript code to your documents. The code should show Browse For File dialog and import selected file to the document. Please have a look at Import Named File Attachment [script](http://www.pdfscripting.com/public/Free_Acrobat_Automation_Tools.cfm) (at the bottom of the page). I doubt that this solution will work in Adobe Reader or alternative PDF viewers, but Acrobat Professional should do the trick.

Another solution is given is [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/721525) on Adobe forums:

> ...I figured out a roundabout way to attach files in adobe reader (not
>   the full blow adobe acrobat reader).   Via Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro I
>   created a blank form with the "comment/mark up" tools enabled.  Then I
>   merged that file with the other PDF form that was formatted with
>   fields, radial buttons etc.  I had to create the blank form for the
>   attachments separately because if I tried to enable the "comment/mark
>   up' tool on the form with fields and radial buttons it disabled the
>   fields.  ... The comment markup tool then allowed me to attach files
>   via the "attach file as a comment" option.